# jquery method .not to remove nested div from string

Tags: jquery

I need to remove one of the nested divs.
I can remove div#parent (+divs inside) with:

```
var $s = $(s).not('div#parent');
```

But i can't remove just one div inside (e.g. div#first):

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><div id="parent"><div id="first"><p>paragraph</p></div><div id="second"><p> second div</p></div></div>';

        var $s = $(s).not('div#parent > div#first');

        $('body').append($s);  // it shows all html
```

how is this scenario done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.not` is actually filtering the top-level elements, which is what `$(s)` returns:

```
> $(s)
[<h1>​heading​</h1>​, <div id=​"parent">​…​</div>​]
```

Since both of them don't match the selector, nothing is removed from the set of matched elements.

Find and remove the elements instead:

```
var $s = $(s);
$s.find('#first').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `remove` after appending it to the body.

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1>
         <div id="parent">
            <div id="first"><p>paragraph</p>
            </div><div id="second"><p> second div</p>
         </div></div>';


$('body').append(s); // it shows all html

$('#first').remove();
```

Comment: i need to have it as a string before i insert it into html so i can't use this one i think